# comparison of two prop in dictionary

Tags: c#

I had to switch my List<> to Dictionary<int,List> now I am struggling how to compare two values.

I need to compare  Ids and i am getting an underline here

```
(m => m.Id == lastOpenedArticle.Id);
```

that 'KeyValuePair<int, Article>' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyValuePair<int, Article>'

The article contains the definition

```
var openedArticle = allOptimizationData.LastOpenedArticles.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == lastOpenedArticle.Id);

public static async void SaveLastOpenedArticle(ArticleDetailData lastOpenedArticle)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(LangUpStorage.OptimalizationDataFolder));
            var allOptimizationData = DeserializeAllOptimizationData();
            
            var openedArticle = allOptimizationData.LastOpenedArticles.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == lastOpenedArticle.Id);
          }
```

Is there a way to achieve comparison like i had when i used List with the dictionary?
Sorry I have never used Dictionary before plus i am a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on the assumption that `LastOpenArticles` is the `Dictionary<int,Article>` that you mentioned:

```
var openedArticle = allOptimizationData.LastOpenedArticles
       .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value.Id == lastOpenedArticle.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyvalue pairs have the Value and the Key properties.

so either m.Key or m.Value.Id depending on how you are using the ids

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: oh, thats the .net core doc but should be the same for framework and standard.